# How do I pass environment variables into sensitive parameters in Parameter Context

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm aware that I can reference an environment variable using the expression language, e.g. `${MY_ENV}`. However sensitive fields don't support expression language. Is there another/better approach?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `EnvironmentVariableParameterProvider` under `ControllerSettings`.
Then you can create a `ParameterContext` with given environment variables and choose which of them are sensitive varaibles. If they're not listed, you may need to set them first and restart nifi.
[image]